# Media Query Not setting for right screen resolution

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My screen resolution is: `1280 x 768`

I have two queries but whatever one is last to activate gets used which is not what i want. The one that gets activated is: 1280 x 720. What i dont get is my screen is 1280 x 768? Why does it not work?

Screen 1280 x 768:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-height: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
{
body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

Screen 1280 x 720:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-height: 720px)  
  and (max-device-width: 1280px)
  and (orientation: landscape) 
{
body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if this could be a problem, but I don't use "...-device-..." just the "min-width" and "max-width". Also, maybe the scrollbar can be a problem. Those are the first ideas that can maybe help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `device-width`/`device-height` has been deprecated
>
> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some
>   browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.
>   Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see [the
>   compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Browser_compatibility). Be aware that this feature may cease to work 
>   at any time.

In this case, when using `min-*`, the query with the highest height value needs to be last or else it does not work

And if you use `min-height`, I guess you'll get the expected result

*Note, it's not the computer's screen width that counts, it's the browsers viewport, so if your computer screen is 1280x768 you need to run the browser in full screen for it to work*

```css
@media only screen and (min-height: 720px) {
  body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 768px) {
  body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

If you also want this to only work on screen with a `max-width`, do like this

```css
@media only screen and (min-height: 720px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 768px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

And of course, limited for landscape will look like this

```css
@media only screen and (min-height: 720px) and (max-width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 768px) and (max-width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But trying to run the snippet, the background color just stays white, not setting for me. When i run the site using the updated code, the queries also dont trigger for me?

Comment: @irishwill200 It stays white until the viewport is higher or equal with 720px **and** wider or equal than 1280px, after that it stays blue until the viewport is higher or equal with 768px **and** wider or equal than 1280px, where it will become green

Comment: @irishwill200 If you change the values (for testing purpose and since your computer has only 1280/768) to 520/568/980 and resize your browser, you will see how it works ... and don't use `orientation: landscape` on desktop, it will make the query to not activate since desktop pc's does not have an orientation value

Comment: Hi @LGSon, Sorry got off work yesterday but i definitely learnt a lot about media queries today! With that said, since my screen is 1280 x 768, what would it be in viewport? How can i get the correct res to use for the screens? Thanks!

Comment: Found a script to grab the viewport information. Thank you very much! Much appreciated.